# How to catch touch event of Feitian nfc card reader in Android?

Tags: android, smartcard-reader, cardreader

I'm having problem when use Feitian NFC card reader model R520 with Android.

The sdk of card reader is `com.ft.mobile.reader.Card` only supports events `OnInsertHeadSet()`, `OnPullHeadSet()`. I can't find an event when touch nfc tag to the reader.

Does anyone know how to catch touch event of a card reader?

For future reference. I create a timer task for scanning device every one second. The only problem now is to set mute the sound of card reader.